# Creating an Index from Principal Component Analysis

Tags: econometrics, index

I have 5 dummy variables, and I want to combine them into one single dummy variable.
Is PCA a valid option? If not, what else can I do?
If I am doing PCA, What issues can I face in the analysis?

PS: I am considering equally dividing the PCA score to create a dummy after applying PCA to 5 variables.